# ngx-resource-core and file attachments

Tags: angular, rest, angular7

I'm using latest version of ngx-resource-core in Angular 7. Is there any way to send a multipart form taking into account that a model can contain files/byte arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 5.3.2, you just need to specify `requestBodyType: ResourceRequestBodyType.FORM_DATA` in `@ResourceAction` and all the `File` or `File[]` members of the entity will be sent as multipart data.